# MaterializeCss, Bower, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bower, materialize

I use materialize css with Bower in Rails project and have a problem:
I try to change color of my footer in `assets/stylesheet/main.sass:`

```
footer
 background-color: #004d40
```

But on the page default color of materialize footer in `vendor/assets/bower_components/materialize/sass/components/_global.scss`
overwriting my style

```
application.scss

/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
*/
$roboto-font-path: 'materialize/font/roboto/';
@import "materialize/sass/materialize.scss";
```

Try to @import matrialize first, but then *= require_tree . not loaded

Answer (score 0):

You need to use @import in scss files. https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass might be easier to use instead of bower for rails.